# Issues with facebook forcing login to use an app

Tags: facebook

I have quite a few FB apps that were available to users without logging to FB. About an hour or two ago all apps were starting with screen, which says: Log in to use your Facebook account with APP_NAME. Unable to access APP_NAME.

I've noticed that FB is having some problems this week, but I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Having the same issue. Can't find any solution